# Azure AD App registration sign in redirect URL removing port number

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have setup an Azure App registration with a redirect URLs as follows:
https://localhost:7133/signin-oidc
https://mydomain:81/signin-oidc
[image: Settings in Azure App registration]
The problem is when trying to login, the redirect URI removes the port number and as a result, the login fails with

> Blockquote AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'XXXX/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'XXXX-XXXX'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this

[image: Sign in error]

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added redirect URI like below:

[image]

For *sample* to authorize users, I used the below endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://xxx:80/signin-oidc
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

And got the same error:

[image]

The error usually occurs if the redirect Uri you are passing to authorize the users doesn't match the redirect Uri in configured for the application in the Azure Portal.

> Blockquote AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'XXXX/sigmin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'XXXX-XXXX'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the
> request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to
> https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this

From the error you pasted I can see that the redirect Uri is `XXXX/sigmin-oidc` which is a typo error that must be  `https://xxx/signin-oidc` not sigmin-oidc.

If the above is not the case, as a workaround to resolve the error try not passing the port number as sometimes the port number is ignored to match a redirect Uri. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#localhost-exceptions).

[image]

Now I am able to **authorize the user** successfully:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://xxx/signin-oidc
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[missing information about port support · Issue #47893 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47893#issuecomment-660244432) by Hirsch Singhal

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo (sigmin).
I assumed the port numbers were only ignored if using localhost.

Comment: Can you try by not passing the port number and check if that works?